# OpenSSL, basic configuration, new_certs_dir, certs

Tags: openssl, config

I've searched for an answer for the differences and using for this two configuration parameters in the openssl-config-file.

```
certs         = ... # Where the issued certs are
```

and

```
new_certs_dir = ... # default place for new certs
```

In the `Network Security with OpenSSL - O'Reilly` book also this two parameters in the default-openssl-config-file, but the `certs` never used and never described.
By my tests with `openssl`, all certificates are stored the folder - defined  by `new_cers_dir`.

What is the difference between these two parameters?
And is the parameter `certs` used somewhere?

Sorry for my mistake. I've ask my question now here:

### https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398280/openssl-basic-configuration-new-certs-dir-certs

regards
raiserle

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is for an wrapper for OpenSSL in PERL. But I'll aks this question on other site.

Comment: If its a programming question, then you should show the relevant code. If you don't show your code, then its just another question on how to use commands. Questions for command usage is better asked on sites like [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).